# Replace a word of a line if matched

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I am given a file. If a line has "xxx" as its third word then I need to replace it with "yyy". My final output must have all the original lines with the modified lines.
*The input file is-*

```
abc xyz mno
xxx xyz abc
abc xyz xxx
abc xxx xxx xxx
```

*The required output file should be*-

```
abc xyz mno
xxx xyz abc
abc xyz yyy
abc xxx yyy xxx
```

I have tried-

```
grep "\bxxx\b" file.txt | awk '{if ($3=="xxx") print $0;}' | sed -e 's/[^ ]*[^ ]/yyy/3'
```

but this gives the output as-

```
abc xyz yyy
abc xxx yyy xxx
```

Comment: this site is not for doing your work.. but to help with something you tried and got stuck.. so please add your attempts to question.. and also, adding sample input/output will help too

Comment: `awk | grep | sed`  is an awful combination `:-/`

Comment: thanks for adding your attempts.. would suggest to go through https://stackoverflow.com/tags/awk/info (replace awk with sed/grep for others) - there are plenty of free resources which help in learning these tools with examples... you were close with `awk '{if ($3=="xxx") print $0;}'` but didn't know how to modify that to suit your use case.. happy learning :)

Answer (score 3):

Following simple `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk '$3=="xxx"{$3="yyy"} 1'   Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
abc xyz mno
xxx xyz abc
abc xyz yyy
abc xxx yyy xxx
```

***Explanation:*** Checking condition here if `$3` 3rd field is equal to string `xxx` then setting `$3`'s value to string `yyy`. Then mentioning `1` there, since `awk` works on method of condition then action. I am making condition TRUE here by mentioning `1` here and NOT mentioning any action here so be default print of current line will happen(either with changed 3rd field or with new 3rd field).

Comment: Worth mentioning that any time you replace fields, awk rewrites the line, replacing whitespace with `OFS`.

Answer (score 1):

**`sed`** solution:

```
sed -E 's/^(([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){2})apathy\>/\1empathy/' file
```

The output:

```
abc xyz mno
apathy xyz abc
abc xyz empathy
abc apathy empathy apathy
```

---

To modify the file *inplace* add `-i` option: `sed -Ei ....`

Comment: Tedious, isn't it? `;-)` ++

Comment: why not use quantifier - that way it would be generic too, changing number to specify column

Comment: @Sundeep, be more exact when talking about "quatifier". There are many quantifiers

Comment: @sjsam, yes, typing `[[:space:]]+` is always finger exercise  )

Comment: the `{n,m}` quantifier... for ex: `(([^[:space:]]+[[:space:]]+){2})`

Comment: @Sundeep, ok, you have my update (looks a bit shorter)

Comment: Yep, now it (structurally) matches my answer. :-)

Answer (score 0):

In general the `awk` command may look like

```
awk '{command set 1}condition{command set 2}' file
```

The `command set 1` would be executed for every line while `command set 2` will be executed if the condition preceding that is true.

> My final output must have all the original lines with the modified
>   lines

In your case

```
 awk 'BEGIN{print "Original File";i=1}
      {print}
      $3=="xxx"{$3="yyy"}
      {rec[i++]=$0}
      END{print "Modified File";for(i=1;i<=NR;i++)print rec[i]}'file
```

should solve that.

**Explanation**

`$3` is the the third space-delimited field in `awk`. If it matches `"xxx"`, then it is replaced. Print the unmodified lines first while storing the modified lines in an array. At the end, print the modified lines. `BEGIN` and `END` blocks are executed only at the beginning and the end respectively. `NR` is the awk built-in variable which denotes that number of records processed till the moment. Since it is used in the `END` block it should give us the total number of records.

All good <kbd>:-)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Ravinder has already provided you with the shortest awk solution possible.

In sed, the following would work:

```
sed -E 's/(([^ ]+ ){2})xxx/\1yyy/'
```

Or if your sed doesn't include `-E`, you can use the more painful BRE notation:

```
sed 's/\(\([^ ][^ ]* \)\{2\}\)xxx/\1yyy/'
```

And if you're in the mood to handle this in bash alone, something like this might work:

```
while read -r line; do
  read -r -a a <<<"$line"
  [[ "${a[2]}" == "xxx" ]] && a[2]="yyy"
  printf '%s ' "${a[@]}"
  printf '\n'
done < input.txt
```